# String format date comparing can be problem in js?

Tags: javascript, date

1. `'2012-12-12' < '2013-11-12'  // true`
2. `new Date('2012-12-12') < new Date('2013-11-12') // true`

Both produce same result.
But when I search some example code comparing string format date, everyone convert it to date type.
Then first example can be problem , But I am not sure when it can be problem. Let me know more detail. please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> '2012-12-12' < '2013-11-12'  // true

Compares the dates as strings. One benefit of ISO 8601 formatting is that timestamps compare correctly as strings provided the offset (if there is one) is the same. E.g.

```
'2022-01-06T09:00:00+10:00' < '2022-01-06T00:00:00Z'
```

should be *true*, but it returns *false*, whereas:

```
new Date('2022-01-06T09:00:00+10:00') < new Date('2022-01-06T00:00:00Z')
```

returns true (see below for why). But comparing other date formats as strings almost certainly won't work, e.g. using d/m/y format:

```
01/03/2020 < 01/02/2021
```

returns false because the "3" in "03" is greater than the "2" in "02" and that's as far as the comparison gets.

Then there is:

> new Date('2012-12-12') < new Date('2013-11-12') // true

which works because both timestamps are parsed as UTC to produce a time value (a number value that is the date's offset from 1 Jan 1970 in milliseconds).  The `<` operator coerces the Date objects to primitives which, in this case, effectively calls *valueOf* which returns the time value, hence the comparison is reduced to:

```
1355270400000 < 1384214400000
```

That's why strings are often parsed to Date objects for comparison. Note however that while:

```
'2022-01-06' == '2022-01-06' // true
```

When converted to Dates:

```
new Date('2022-01-06') == new Date('2022-01-06') // false
```

because two objects (Date or other) are never `==` or `===` to each other, so:

```
new Date(/* anything */) == new Date(/* anything */)
```

is always false, even if both Date objects represent invalid dates. If you want to see if they're equal, compare the time values:

```
new Date('2022-01-06').getTime() == new Date('2022-01-06').getTime()
```

But be careful when parsing strings, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

Don't ever use string literals for dates (especially in JavaScript where everything is a duck) for comparison!

Dates and DateTimes are weird and strange and not actually usable in programming, but since we need to do something with it we kinda "jumped around the whole - this is insane - part".

Just for fun you might want to read Jon Skeet's blog post about it: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/

But just for the sake of argument, compare a date with a literal date will resolve in `'2021-02-23' < 'AA'` which is also true or false (didn't try it), but for JavaScript the comparison is alike, there is no type comparison, it's just values.

Comment: "*Don't ever use string literals for dates*" is not reasonable advice. One of the benefits of ISO 8601 formatting is that dates compare correctly as strings. Also "*for JavaScript … there is no type comparison*" ignores that the OP is comparing strings, so there is no issue with type and there is `===` (hence `'2020-11-21' === '2020-11-21'` returns *true*).